# Quitting a program if a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript

I want the program to quit if there is no student name, or if marks entered are not between 0 and 100:

```
var student = prompt("Please enter a student name [Press Cancel to exit]", "Cancel");

while(student !== null) {
    studentName.push(student);
    student = prompt("Please enter a student name [Press Cancel to exit]","Cancel");
}

function checkStudent() {
    for(var i = 0;i<studentName;i++) {
        if(studentName === null) {
          break;
        }
    }
    return document.write("We can't proceed if there is no student name");
}

checkStudent();

var mark = prompt("Please enter a mark[Press Cancel to exit]","Cancel");

while(mark!== null) {
    marks.push(mark);
    mark = prompt("Please enter a mark[Press Cancel to exit]", "Cancel");
}

function checkMark() {
    if(mark< 0 || 100<mark) {
        return
    }
}

checkMark()

document.write("Please enter a mark between 0 and 100")
```

Comment: break; ? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: because the check does not happen in the loop? And not sure how an array can be null.

Comment: There is no such concept as "program quitting" in javascript. I suggest that you find a basic programming tutorial or reword your question into what you really need.

Comment: Wrap it in a function and `return`;

Comment: Please be more specific in describing the desired behavior. For example, do you want the browser to quit or redirect to another page if the conditions are not met?